# Get the output of a specific layer as the result on test data in place of last layer (auto-encoder latent features) in keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to get the output of the `latent layer/hidden layer` to use it as input for something else. I trained my model in an efficient way to minimize the loss so my model could learn the latent features efficiently and as close as possible to the image. 
My model is

```
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

#Encoder
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x) 


# Decoder
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded) 
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x) # opposite of Pooling
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

I want the output of `encoded` layer as my output for the model. Is it possible? ad If yes, Please tell me how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply do in this way

```
autoencoder.fit(...)

latent_model = Model(input_img, encoded)
latent_representation = latent_model.predict(X)
```

Comment: How is that Supposed to work? Won't the weights change because instantiating the whole `Model` object again?

Comment: no, the weights are the same, you are not recompiling your model and you aren't defining new layer. you are simply reusing what you have created (and trained before)